# How can I resize a watermark on an image with PHP?

Tags: php, gd

Hi i'm trying to resize watermark png on uploaded images, but just can't figure it out, what i'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
// BEGIN WATERMARK

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng ('watermark.png');
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);
$_Dim[x] = imageSX($destImage);
$_Dim[y] = imageSY($destImage);
$logo_Dim[x] = imageSX($watermark);
$logo_Dim[y] = imageSY($watermark);
$x = $_Dim[x] - $logo_Dim[x];
$y = $_Dim[y] - $logo_Dim[y];
imagecopy ($destImage, $watermark, $x, $y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
imagedestroy ($watermark);

// END WATERMARK
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function for resize your stamp. Don't use the `imagecopyresized` because it corrupts your image and you will take lower quality. Better is `imagecopyresampled`.
`imagesavealpha` and `imagealphablending` provide you make the transparent background for you stamp

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('The_img.jpg'));
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('the_watermark.png');

$stamp_new = imagecreatetruecolor(100,50);
imagealphablending($stamp_new, false);
imagesavealpha($stamp_new, true);
imagecopyresampled($stamp_new, $stamp, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 50, imagesx($stamp),imagesy($stamp));

$margin = ['right' => 20, 'bottom' => 20]; // Смещение от края
imagecopy($image, $stamp_new,
imagesx($image) - imagesx($stamp_new) - $margin['right'],
imagesy($image) - imagesy($stamp_new) - $margin['bottom'],
0, 0, imagesx($stamp_new), imagesy($stamp_new));
$imageName = 'newimage.jpg';
$dirName = 'test_folder';
if(!file_exists($dirName)){
    mkdir($dirName, 0755, true);
    imagepng($image, $dirName.'/'.$imageName);
} else {
    imagepng($image, $dirName.'/'.$imageName);
}

ImageDestroy($image);
ImageDestroy($stamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use: [`imagecopyresized`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) or [`imagecopyresampled`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

```
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng ('watermark.png');
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);

// this is an example to resized your watermark to 0.5% from their original size.
// You can change this with your specific new sizes.
$percent = 0.5;
$newwidth = $watermark_width * $percent;
$newheight = $watermark_height * $percent;

// create a new image with the new dimension.
$new_watermark = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

// Retain image transparency for your watermark, if any.
imagealphablending($new_watermark, false);
imagesavealpha($new_watermark, true);

// copy $watermark, and resized, into $new_watermark
// change to `imagecopyresampled` for better quality
imagecopyresized($new_watermark, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);

$_Dim[x] = imageSX($destImage);
$_Dim[y] = imageSY($destImage);
$logo_Dim[x] = imageSX($new_watermark);
$logo_Dim[y] = imageSY($new_watermark);
$x = $_Dim[x] - $logo_Dim[x];
$y = $_Dim[y] - $logo_Dim[y];
imagecopy ($destImage, $new_watermark, $x, $y, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight);
imagedestroy ($new_watermark);
```

<del>**Note**: I'm assuming you have another `imageSX` & `imageSY` functions, because the built-in functions are in all low-case: `imagesx` & `imagesy`.</del>

**Edit 1**: function name in php are not case-sensitive, but its a good practice to call functions as they appear in their declaration.

**Edit 2**: Add more code to retain transparency.

Comment: Everything in PHP is case insensitive. Sad but true.

Comment: It works like a charm. You saved my evening, thank you cwps.

Comment: @miken32 At least it's consistent :-)

Comment: @miken32 I just found out Function in php are not case-sensitive. Oh my god! My whole life has been a lie.

Comment: @AlesTom would you be so kind to accept this answer. :)

Comment: `imagecopyresampled`  has a far superior output quality to imagecopyresized and should be used in preference in all cases.

Comment: Just after $new_watermark = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight); you must put in imagealphablending($new_watermark, false); imagesavealpha($new_watermark, true); if not, img is not transparent. But script works like a charm :-) Thank you cwps. How can i accept this answer?

Comment: @Ales Thank you, I'll edit my answer for the transparancy. To accept, I think clicking 'checkmark' on the left side of my answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235.